# TYPO3 form validation not working if only radio buttons are used

Tags: validation, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have some trouble with a multistep form because the validation for a single step which contains a form with only radio buttons are not working :(

I have a simple property **type** which represent a radio button value:

```
class Step1Data extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

/**
 * type
 * 
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $type;

/**
 * Returns the type
 * 
 * @return string $type
 */
public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Sets the type
 * 
 * @param string $type
 * @return void
 */
public function setType($type) {
    $this->type = $type;
}

}
```

the fluid mark-up looks as follows for this step:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">
    <f:form action="step1redirect" class="step1" name="step1data" object="{step1data}">
         <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'step1data.type'}" />
         <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="type-1" />
            type 1
         </label>
         <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="type-2" />
            type 2
         </label>
         <f:form.submit value="next" />           
    </f:form>
</f:section>
```

the controller actions for this step are:

```
/**
 * Step1
 *
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data
 * @ignorevalidation $step1data
 */
public function step1Action(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data = NULL) {

    if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step1data') && $step1data == NULL) {
        $step1data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step1data'));
    }

    $this->view->assign('step1data', $step1data);

}

/**
 * Step1 redirect action
 *
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data
 */
public function step1redirectAction(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data) {

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step1data', serialize($step1data));
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();

    $this->redirect('step2');

}
```

If I add an example second property **name** of type string with NotEmpty annotation and a fluid textfield to this form like:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">
    <f:form action="step1redirect" class="step1" name="step1data" object="{step1data}">
         <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'step1data.type'}" />
         <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="type-1" />
            type 1
         </label>
         <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="type-2" />
            type 2
         </label>

         <!-- EXAMPLE second property -->
         <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'step1data.name'}"/>  
         <f:form.textfield property="name" />
         <!-- EXAMPLE second property -->

         <f:form.submit value="next" />           
    </f:form>
</f:section>
```

the validation is working. The validation also works if I have only the textfield on this form, but if I have only the radio buttons without a textfield on this form the validation is not working and an error appears because the step1data object is null.

I don't know the reason for this weird problem, hope you can help me?

Comment: can no one reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is a hidden input field above the radio buttons with the same property name:

```
    <f:form.hidden property="type" />
    <div class="group-block">
        <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="wish1" />
            type1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="group-block">
        <label>
            <f:form.radio property="type" value="wish2" />
            type2
        </label>
    </div>
```

so firstly the hidden field would be checked and validated and if a radio button is checked then the type property will be overwritten